# How to group multiple entries in a column and find the occurrence(frequency) of each observation in R?

Tags: r

[image: The image shows the app and its category]

How to write a R code which shows the output like:

[image]

Comment: Just use `table(df1$Categories)`

Comment: o/p: < table of extent 0 >